# How to place widgets side by side, whilst being aligned to the window borders?

Tags: python, guizero

I am trying to create a basic python program using the guizero library. I want to create a push button and a text widget and place them side by side, with the button in the top left corner and the text widget in the top centre. However, the text widget is aligned between the button and the border of the window, so not truly centered. How would I fix this?

```
top_box = Box(root,width="fill",layout="grid")

settings = PushButton(top_box,text="Settings",grid=[0,0])

title_text = Text(top_box,grid=[1,0],size=50,text="Insert text")
```